# how to Prime React dropdown multiple columns in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend, primereact

[How can I create a Prime React with the dropdown box shown in this photo? Only Prime React JS (Java Script)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXJbH.png)

[I have attached the photo as per what I want in Prime React.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NoKK.png)

I want a combo in Prime React like the combo box shows in the photo so that when the user selects they know what they are selecting by verifying the information.

I want that combo prime in React JS.